# Doubts with this vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

Good afternoon, I'm doing this exercise: Finding the quotient vector space $\mathbb{Q_2[x]}/span\{3,2x^2-x+1,4x^2-2x+5\}$.

My work:

Let's call $W=span\{3,2x^2-x+1,4x^2-2x+5\}$, I have already calculated $W$ and I get as a result that $W=\{a+bx+cx^2\in\mathbb{Q_2[x]}:2b+c=0\}=span\{1,-1/2x+x^2\}$. My question is in what I do not know how to find the class of any element of the quotient, since I know that if $v$ and $u$ are in $\mathbb{Q_2[x]}$ You have to $vRu$ iff $v-u\in W$. Now be $v(x)=b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2$ and $u(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2$ then $v-u=(b_0-a_0)+(b_1-a_1)x+(b_2-a_2)x^2$. And for this difference to belong to $W$ it must occur that $2(b_1-a_1)+(b_2-a_2)=0$. But I got stuck on how to write the class of equivalence of $u$, ie the set $u+W$?.

If you can help me with my doubts, I will be very grateful !!!

Comment: $\Bbb{Q}_2[x]/W$ has dimension $3-2=1$. So, you just need to find some nonzero vector (for example $x+W$) spanning your space.

Comment: @Crostul But how would be the equivalence class of any polynomial, ie the set written by understanding?

Comment: Well, $x+W= \{ x+w : w \in W\}$. Now, if you want this to be more explicit, you can write $$x+W= \{ x+ a(3) + b(2x^2-x+1) + c(4x^2-2x+5) : a,b,c \in \Bbb{Q} \}$$

Comment: @Crostul Sorry, but it's still not clear to me :, this you wrote  would be the class of the any polynomial in the quotient?. What would be the class of $p(x)=3x^2-8x+1$?

Comment: @Crostul Also how can I use the fact that $W=\{a+bx+cx^2\in\mathbb{Q_2[x]}:2b+c=0\}=span\{1,-1/2x+x^2\}$ to write the set $u+W$ with $u \in \mathbb{Q_2[x]}$??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your spanning vectors for $W$, consider a general polynomial $ax^2+bx+c \in \mathbb{Q_2}[x]$.
\begin{align*}
ax^2+bx+c & =a\left(x^2-\frac{x}{2}\right)+c(1)+x\left(b+\frac{a}{2}\right)
\end{align*}
The first two terms are elements of $W$, thus we have that 
$$ax^2+bx+c \equiv x\left(b+\frac{a}{2}\right) \pmod{W}$$

Based on this we can say, for example,
$$3x^2-8x+1 \equiv x\left(-8+\frac{3}{2}\right) \equiv \frac{-13}{2}x\pmod{W}$$

The quotient vector space is generated by $x+W$, hence is one-dimensional.

Comment: But what would be the explicit form of the set $x+W$?

Comment: $x+W=\{a(x^2-x/2)+c:a,c \in \mathbb{Q})\}$?

Comment: @DanielaRondón I think you forgot to add $x$ in the description.

Comment: Ummm, but I have a doubt, that $x$ is the monomial $x$ or refers to the general polynomial $x=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2$?